# How to use decorator achieve listen except for Python 3.6?

Tags: python

I want to use decorator listen execpt,But the exception is not displayed in function_listen.
I hope it can be listen ,But Python seems unable to do so

```
def function_listen(func):
    try:
        def wapper(*args,**kwargs):
            return func(args,kwargs)
    except Exception:
        print(func.__name__+"ERROR")

@function_listen
def test():
    print(1/0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

C:\Python\Python36\python36.exe D:/MyCode/py/a.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/MyCode/py/a.py", line 12, in

test()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decorator should return a function, yours returns `None`. You also called `func` with the wrong arguments.

```
def function_listen(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            print(func.__name__ + "ERROR")
    return wrapper


@function_listen
def test():
    print(1/0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

# testERROR
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem